# Guest author's post not display in author template

Tags: templates, author

I am using this filter to display guest author on post, but i want guest author's posts to appear in the `author.php` template also.

This is my guest author code (inside `functions.php`).

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_author', 'guest_author_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'guest_author_name' );
function guest_author_name( $name ) {
    global $post;

    $author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'guest-author', true );

    if ( $author )
        $name = $author;
    return $name;
}
?>
```

...and here is the author template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File

Comment: if you make a subscriber level user and assign the post to that user should be able to load his posts on `author.php` template..

Comment: @Otto Please do a full edit, when editing a post. Edits are "expensive", which means, the question is transformed to a "community wiki" after too many edits. Thanks.

Comment: @user8503/OP Please make use of the WYSIWYG editor when asking or answering. And please use upper-/lowercase characters. At least this isn't chat.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user with a role such as subscriber so they cant do anything in the backend, and assign the post to that user. Doing this would be a lot easier than the hours of custom coding needed to get things working using your system.