# WP-PageNavi not working on Custom page Template

Tags: plugin-wp-pagenavi

this is my code in Custom page Template

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=8'); ?>    
<?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>
```

& this is wp_pagenavi code

```
<div class="more_entries">
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); else { ?><?php } ?></div>
</div>
```

page numbers showing but navigation not working

Comment: i have tried all 'paged' solution, but failed. finally this old method works! http://theodin.co.uk/blog/design/wordpress-pagination-wppagenavi-queryposts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like **Old Famous Problem** with `paged`

try this for `quey_posts();`

```
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 query_posts(array(
   'posts_per_page' => 8,
   'paged' => $paged
  )
 );
```

Comment: dear could you plz look at this ? i dont know what is the bug http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32130/guest-authors-post-not-display-in-author-template